# How to do "page up" while browsing unix "man" command pages?

Tags: unix

I know I can do a "page down" using keyboard "spacebar" while browsing "man" command output on unix terminal window. Is there a corresponding keyboard shortcut for "page up"? To be generic, is there a list of keyboard shortcuts for man command? I did "man man" with no luck.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It depends on the pager that the `man` command uses on your system.

If it is `less` (as in 'less is more'), then you can go backwards. (With `less`, <kbd>b</kbd> goes back a page, amongst other options for doing that; so does <kbd>Control-B</kbd>.  The <kbd>h</kbd> command gives me several pages full of options that I seldom or never use.)

If the pager is `more` (as in ... oh, there isn't an inverse jibe), then the answer may well be 'No, you cannot go backwards'.

On Mac OS X (10.7.4), the `man man` command cites the environment variables MANPAGER and HTMLPAGER that can be set; the default MANPAGER is `less`.

Comment: "out of scope" or no, great answer, thanks!

Answer (score 20):

You can type <kbd>h</kbd> for help.

Type <kbd>Ctrl-f</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-b</kbd> to scroll down and up.

---

<kbd>Ctrl-d</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-u</kbd> will scroll half window.

Comment: Hehe, didn't know about Ctrl + d.

Comment: Be careful while using ctrl-d. Ctrl-d also is a shortcut to exit bash. If you are in a scroll frenzy while scrolling through a long document, you might exit the shell inadvertently.

Answer (score 4):

Page Up = CTRL + B
Page Down = CTRL + F

Answer (score 0):

`C-v` (aka <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd> or `^V`) and `M-v` (aka <kbd>ESC-v</kbd>, <kbd>Alt-v</kbd> or <kbd>Meta-v</kbd>) also work with `less` (to scroll down and up, respectively), for those familiar with Emacs keybindings.